# Port-Forwarding issues specifically with Flask, but not express.js

Tags: networking, arch-linux, services, webserver, port-forwarding

I have a server (Arch Linux) running locally with a couple of services on it, and I wanted to add a new python service (Flask) running on a different port. Locally, the server is running on `192.168.x.x`, and I can already access all of the services currently running on it. I started my Flask server on port `5000`, however running nmap on my laptop showed that the port was still closed:

```
mylaptop~$ nmap 192.168.x.x

PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
3000/tcp open  ppp
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

However, the port was open on the server's localhost

```
myserver~$ nmap localhost

PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
3000/tcp open  ppp
5000/tcp open  upnp
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

I assumed that it was some sort of issue with iptables (which I'm mostly unfamiliar with), but I tried running an express.js server (I already had one running on port `3000`) on port `5000`, and sure enough it worked.

```
mylaptop~$ nmap 192.168.x.x

PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
3000/tcp open  ppp
5000/tcp open  upnp
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

I'm still unsure on how to forward the Flask server, and also I'm curious as to why my ssh, express.js and postgres services are forwarded by default. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure of you last "screenshot"? It reads `mylaptop~$ nmap localhost`. It seems not pertinent to me.

Comment: @andcoz Thats my bad: I was trying to simplify it. I just tested it again, and it should be `mylaptop~$ 192.168.x.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Flasks built in HTTP server, then this is explained in the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) (scroll down to Externally Visible Server):

> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network, you can make the server publicly available simply by adding --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> > flask run --host=0.0.0.0
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

The `nmap` output on your `myserver` machine showed port 5000 as open because you used `nmap localhost`, which scans for opens ports on localhost aka 127.0.0.1, not 192.168.x.x.

Comment: This works great, thanks! I also found that if you want to do the same thing in code, you can do `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`